# Visual Studio - NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined

Tags: python, visual-studio, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to display a simple window using the python Tkinter module in visual studio community 2015. Whenever I tried I get an error message
Here is the code:

```
  from tkinter import *

  root = Tk()
  theLabel = Labe1(root, text="This is too easy")
  theLabel1.pack()
  root.mainloop()
```

Here is the error message:

```
NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: It's strange you didn't get an error from the `from tkinter import *` if there was a problem. Try running a file with `import tkinter`, then `print(sorted(dir(tkinter)))` and verify that `Tk` is one of the list items printed out.

Comment: You're also going to have a problem from using `Labe1` instead of `Label` and similarly because there's nothing named `theLabel1`.

Comment: Did you name your file "tkinter.py"?

Comment: Byran Oakley: I did name my file tkinter.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get this result if you have some other module in your pythonpath named "tkinter". For example, if you name your program "tkinter.py", or if a file named "tkinter.py" is somewhere in your path.

The fix is to simply rename your file. When you do "import tkinter", it's importing your file rather than the tkinter module.

An easy way to check what was actually imported is to do this:

```
import tkinter
print("the imported file is", tkinter.__file__)
```

Comment: @nathansiafa: rename your file.

Answer (score 1):

Looking through some of my other code I noticed one that did the same thing you are trying to do. I modified the your code to match what I had found and I was able to get it to work.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

root = tk.Tk()
Label(root, text="This is too easy").grid(row=0,column=0)
mainloop()
```

I have started to use grid instead of pack because it allows more control over the placement of your items.
I have noticed that I get the same error sometimes. Importing tkinter itself is the only way I have found to get around it.

Comment: Your answer doesn't address the OP's problem at all.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was looking at three code windows and grabbed the wrong one.

Comment: When i tried your method I got this error:                                               'module' object has no attribute 'Tk'

Comment: I agree with @Bryan Oakley. If you are getting the module error then it must not be importing the right tkinter module. Because I use the this method all the time. It makes calling the tkinter module a lot simpler for different widgets.