# Python easygui , global name 'Tk' is not defined

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, easygui

I am trying to execute the following code snippet:

```
import easygui
from Tkinter import *
easygui.msgbox('Hello')
```

but it returns the following error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-28d6ffa54e48> in <module>()
----> 1 easygui.msgbox('Hello')

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easygui/boxes/derived_boxes.pyc in msgbox(msg, title, ok_button, image, root)
    214                         root=root,
    215                         default_choice=ok_button,
--> 216                         cancel_choice=ok_button)
    217 
    218 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easygui/boxes/base_boxes.pyc in buttonbox(msg, title, choices, image, root, default_choice, cancel_choice)
     64         boxRoot.withdraw()
     65     else:
---> 66         boxRoot = Tk()
     67         boxRoot.withdraw()
     68 

NameError: global name 'Tk' is not defined
```

I tried troubleshooting with various combinations of importing Tkinter -

```
import Tkinter as Tk  
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
```

but none of them work. I have the latest version of both packages installed. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31897127) helps.

Having a file named 'Tkinter' in the same directory as your script causes to import this file rather than Tkinter itself

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 3+ Python then its "tkinter" not "Tkinter"

If thats not the problem then check your path to tkinter which should be

"\python??\lib\tkinter"

?? being the version you have and tkinter will be a folder of many py files.

Python is case sensitive.